# Django--Model Construction (User Profile or Seperate Model)

Tags: mysql, django, models

The phrasing of the title may be a little confusing.  I have an app that has users with varying permission levels (admin and non-admin).

I was unsure which of the following constructs was preferable: just go with User_Profile and add an admin field or create two models (one for admin and one for )

```
class User_Profile(models.Model):       
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    employer=models.ForeignKey(Company,blank=True)
    admin=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    phone=models.CharField(blank=True)
```

Is this preferable to creating a separate table for Admins that just links to User and Employer through ForeignKeys?  My views will be checking each user for Admin status, so I was concerned that querying a large User_Profile table over and over again might become expensive.

Probably not at the stage to optimize this, but I'm just curious about best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd actually recommend Django's built in user permissions over either of those options:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#methods

Here's a quick tutorial to help you get started:
http://parand.com/say/index.php/2010/02/19/django-using-the-permission-system/

Comment: That tutorial is awesome.  I'm aware of the Group/Permission functionality of Django but have never used it before.  Here's the thing though, I'm not sure how to implement it in this case.  Should I just create a group dynamically for each company """company=Group(companyX)""" and then create a second group for the admin of that company """company_admin=Group(companyX_admin)""" ?  That seems like the way to handle it in this case but feels a tad bit clunky...maybe not.

Comment: Also, just so I can keep getting better at coding, I'm curious why this method is preferable.  With my original option, I would have had to join User (from the request object) to User Profile and then look up admin column.  Now I go from User to Groups through a M2M relationship. Is that right? Why is that better? Thanks so much RS!

Comment: @Brandon Django actually associates permissions with Models, not model instances, which it sounds like you'd like to do (there is no universal set of admins, instead each company will have its own set of admins.) I believe that in this case you may actually be better off adding an admin field to your UserProfile. That is preferable to creating an Admin model. If you haven't already, check out this tutorial on extending the User model with a UserProfile model which should help reduce the number of queries: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/06/django-tips-extending-user-model/

Comment: Thanks rolling.  I'm actually familiar with extending the User model.  I know that you can take advantage of certain manager naming conventions.  Didn't think it was that much better than a simple Foreign Key relationship but I'll check it out again.